# ODP.NET : Error while executing create- select- alter- select or create - select - drop - create - select

Tags: odp.net

I am using ODP.NET for a project. It requires writing queries and executing it from a web interface. 
Problem Statement:- When I create a table and then do some insertion and then selecting the data. Till now every thing works fine.Now I alter the table structure by adding one or more columns and firing the select query. It shows exception- Index out of the bounds if I had altered table by adding some columns while shows variable not found in select list if i drop some column while altering the table. While in actual I am simply using select * from table. 
I thought it may be related to some statement caching by dot net. So I used connection.PurgeStatementCache. But it has also not worked. Please guide me through this problem.

Comment: What's the full ORA error numbers and error messages? This may not be ODP.NET specific and a google search on that error numbers will possibly pay dividends.

Comment: By default ODP.NET uses a connection pool inside OracleConnection object and some state may be somehow be being maintained in the connections inside there. Try killing the process that is using ODP.NET and restart it. If a web server, kill it and restart it.

Comment: The error is not odp.net specific. Its a common error like Index out of bounds if while altering I added one more column or Variable not in select list if I dropped one column.

Comment: Regardless, please edit your question to provide all error numbers and error text you are receiving  to maximize the chance that you can get an answer. You probably should also provide the SQL you are issuing and where possible a describe of the table.

Comment: I got the problem. The problem is neither with code nor with table or query. The problem is that Oracle Server is returning cached results when I fire a select statement again even though the table structure has chaged. So I need to figure out ways to prevent oracle from sending OPD.NET the cached results in case table has changed.